# Why last_update from mysql.innodb_table_stats is different from UPDATE_TIME in information_schema.tables?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to determine using a user that has access to specific schema when was a table last updated.

As a root, when I run `SELECT * FROM mysql.innodb_table_stats WHERE table_name = 'table';` I get a datetime in the column `UPDATE_TIME`

As a user, when I run `SELECT UPDATE_TIME, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database' ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME;` for the same table schema,on `UPDATE_TIME` I get null.

Why does this happen?

How do I get the datetime for the last  update on a specific table?

Is it a security risk to give user access to schema `mysql`?

Comment: What version of MySQL? In some versions, the UPDATE_TIME in the information_schema was NULL for InnoDB tables, because it hadn't been implemented to show it in the information_schema handlers. I think that this has been fixed in recent versions of MySQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin version 8.0.21

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-tables-table.html says:

> ## UPDATE_TIME
>
> When the data file was last updated. For some storage engines, this
> value is NULL. For example, InnoDB stores multiple tables in its
> system tablespace and the data file timestamp does not apply. Even
> with file-per-table mode with each InnoDB table in a separate .ibd
> file, change buffering can delay the write to the data file, so the
> file modification time is different from the time of the last insert,
> update, or delete. For MyISAM, the data file timestamp is used;
> however, on Windows the timestamp is not updated by updates, so the
> value is inaccurate.
>
> UPDATE_TIME displays a timestamp value for the last UPDATE, INSERT, or
> DELETE performed on InnoDB tables that are not partitioned. For MVCC,
> the timestamp value reflects the COMMIT time, which is considered the
> last update time. Timestamps are not persisted when the server is
> restarted or when the table is evicted from the InnoDB data dictionary
> cache.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html#innodb-persistent-stats-tables says:

> Table 15.6 Columns of innodb_table_stats
>
> ...
>
> `last_update` A timestamp indicating the last time that InnoDB updated this row

So that update time is the last update time of the row in the `innodb_table_stats` table, not the last update time of the respective InnoDB table.